# Synonym for correct ending with -ent?

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a synonym for a word like correct, true, right, well-formed or "not misleading", "without error" -

but it should end with -ent.

The closest I can come is "confident", but it doesn't really work as it has to apply to data or observations, not to people.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT 2: Example of sentence:

"The data must be consistent (in terms of input codes etc.), sufficient (i.e. in large volumes with no or very few missing observations), pertinent (i.e observations relevant to the analyses) and -----ent (i.e. the observations must be correctly recorded)."

It doesn't have to end with -ment, just with -ent.

EDIT: I've tried looking up synonyms and synonyms of synonyms etc. on three to four different online dictionaries. I also came across "decent" and "diligent", but they don't really work either. Thus, it is not a question that can just be looked up using commonly available resources. I'm not an English learner, either. Please remove the hold again as the forum suggested is not more suited for this question.

Comment: Are you asking because you _know_ there is such a word, you just can’t think of it? Or do you just, for some reason, require a word with that meaning that ends in _-ent_, but you don’t know if there really is such a word at all? The closest I can think of would be **inerrant**, which is far rarer than its more common cousin, **unerring**.

Comment: The latter. I'm trying to compile a four item list of necessary qualities for good data, and I noticed that (by accident rather than design) the first three words (consistent, sufficient and pertinent) all end in -ent. English is a very rich language so I am almost sure there must be a suitable word :)

Comment: "English is a very rich language" is not a valid reason. (It is also decidedly untrue.) More to the point, however: http://www.wordbyletter.com/suffixes/words_finishing_with_ent.php

Comment: @RegDwigнt You *don't* think English is a rich language? I would love to hear your thoughts on that; or do you simply mean English relies more heavily on syntax than morphology, unlike, eg, Latin?

Comment: It is definitely not untrue. There are 470,000 entries in Webster's dictionary, and this website http://www.languagemonitor.com/number-of-words/number-of-words-in-the-english-language-1008879/ reports the number of words in English to be over 1,000,000 - in my native language, in comparison, there are about about 100,000 - 150,000 words according to answers.com (I think a factor ten to English is rather overestimated, but I guess a factor six could be true). If that doesn't make English rich, I think we need to discuss what it means for a language to be rich :)

Comment: This question reads like a crossword puzzle. Why not clearly state that for harmonic / stylistic purposes you need a word ending with the suffix *-ment*? Could you also provide an example of a sentence using this word? Thank you.

Comment: Given the further edits and clarifications, I have voted to re-open this question.  And now I'm gonna spend like 4 hours digging through scores of -ent words ...  (Why can't there be a tool that lets you type in a letter pattern, a part of speech, and another word which must be able to be reached within 2-3 "synonym links"?)

Comment: The link that RegDwight posted leads to an exasperatingly long list of -ent words, but it only lists the words, not even if they're nouns or adjectives or whatever. Maybe your suggestion will be a task for future google programmers? :)

Answer (score 1):

*"Relevant"* is too close to "pertinent", but you could try ***"cogent"***.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cogent